# Logic of No of count of row with the value of column of column

Tags: sql, asp.net-core-mvc

I write a SQL query for getting the number of rows using `WHERE` clause with the city.

My code is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM rent 
WHERE city = 'Lahore';
```

This successfully returns the result. But now I make logic of getting number of count where in which row has city name and by that name in which row that name exist that row count. Simply mean that I don't want to define the city column value, it restricts my result.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Some sample data to illustrate would probably help.

Comment: i just say that i do not want to write the value of city column in the code then how i get the number of count of row . because there are multiple name of city i want each city of number of count. so if i give the value of city then it restrict my result and gives just that rows where that city exist

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're asking for a count of each unique city?

```
select City, count(*) as CityCount
from Rent
group by City
order by CityCount desc;  // Show highest count first
```

Comment: its nice, i create an html page in asp.net-core-mvc where i access data with id and shows with an loop forexample then loop start and it shows the data where id=1 is this code also show the count of city that exist in id=1